# LUIS - How to handle untterances

Tags: artificial-intelligence, software-design, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a `LUIS` app for extracting the end start date from a sentence.
The utterances I might get as input from users is as follows:

1) start date is 12/2/2020 and end date is 1/3/2030

2) starts on 12/3/2020 and lasts for three years

For the first I have handled. I am stuck on how to handle the second case

Answer (score 0):

If [DatetimeV2 range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-datetimev2?tabs=1-1%2C2-1%2C3-1%2C4-1%2C5-1%2C6-1) is not giving proper results, you need to parse the utterance manually.

First check the response for anything helpful (like a date or a number) and work with that. If there's nothing else besides the start date, use a NLP library to extract some data. The accuracy will not be guaranteed though.

Also consider adding utterances to an intent. Like

```
Starts on {date} and last for {date}
```

This is an evolutionary process, monitor user input and add more utterances on the go.